# Generate all possibilities of a set of alphanumeric with custom conditions

Tags: python, string, arraylist, conditional-statements, generator

I want to generate all the possibilities of a set of alphanumeric "abcdef0123456789" in a length of 64
I know that the number  of possibilities are petabytes huge, so I want to limit it with 3 conditions:

1. the letter or number shouldn't be used more than 8 times in a single string,
   ex: aaababaabaab not acceptable
   aaabaaabaa is acceptable
2. there is no more than 3 adjacent identical letters or numbers
   ex: aaaab not acceptable
   aaaba is acceptable
3. the option of excluding the use 1 or 2 characters of the set
   ex: "bcdef0123456789" with no a

I have searched over the internet for 3 days and never got an answer, could you please help?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internet doesn't have answer to all concrete questions :) You need to break your problem into small pieces and search for them.

If you want to solve these kind of problems you might want to lookup backtracking. It's a generic way to solve constraint problems. You'll do recursion, start with empty string and in each step you'll try to add a character to your string. If one of rules are broken you'll return out of recursion.

Anyway I don't think it's possible, my educated guess is the number of possibilities is much much more than "peta byte".

```
>>> 16 ** 64
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
```

Of course your constraints will reduce this but I don't think more than a mere few digits.